# Java: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (openjdk)

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, ssl, certificate

I want to connect to a site via HttpURLConnection. First of all I stumbled accross *javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException*, as I've forgotten to add the carcerts via *keytool -importcert* for the site under .../lib/security. After that, the connection could have been established with ease.

However, today it's not working anymore, without changing code nor anything else. Following exception is seemed to be thrown:

```
 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the 
 trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

Even though there are plenty of possible solutions on the net, none of them could me get rid off this error.

Maybe there is some setup needed to be done inside eclipse?

Comment: I also have same problem (in my case OpenJDK 11 on NetBSD 9.1)

Comment: Same on Gentoo, OpenJDK 11.0.18. I saw somewhere it's a damned key that isn't installed. If I confirm and fix it, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE!

All of my JDKs and JREs have bad symlinks to `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts` and this appears to be the root cause. On my system, JDKs are installed into `/usr/opt` but the installer fatally expected to be able to access the symlink via a bad relative path:

```
# ll /usr/opt/openjdk-*/lib/security/cacerts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Sep 20 23:48 /usr/opt/openjdk-bin-11.0.18_p10/lib/security/cacerts -> /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Sep 20 23:48 /usr/opt/openjdk-bin-11/lib/security/cacerts -> ../../../../etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Mar  8  2023 /usr/opt/openjdk-bin-17.0.6_p10/lib/security/cacerts -> ../../../../etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Mar  8  2023 /usr/opt/openjdk-bin-17/lib/security/cacerts -> ../../../../etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Mar  6  2023 /usr/opt/openjdk-jre-bin-11.0.12_p7/lib/security/cacerts -> ../../../../etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Mar  6  2023 /usr/opt/openjdk-jre-bin-11/lib/security/cacerts -> ../../../../etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Mar  6  2023 /usr/opt/openjdk-jre-bin-8.362_p09/lib/security/cacerts -> ../../../../etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Mar  6  2023 /usr/opt/openjdk-jre-bin-8/lib/security/cacerts -> ../../../../etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
```

But you'll need to figure out where your JVMs are installed. On my Debian laptop they are in `/usr/lib/jvm`.

So to fix this without having to reinstall, I would suggest the following.

1. Make sure this is really the cause first. Do a long listing and make sure you're seeing broken symlinks. (if you have `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` they will be annoyingly blinking red)

```
ls -alF /usr/opt/openjdk-*/lib/security/cacerts
# or
ls -alF /usr/lib/jvm/*/lib/security/cacerts
```

If you see those tags blinking until the end of days, then you can first test this as a normal user (you should get permission denied) and then run it as root. Change the path and pattern to what matches on your system

```bash
for f in $(ls /usr/opt/openjdk-*/lib/security/cacerts); do
    [[ -e $f ]] || ln -sf /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts $f;
done
```

#### ORIGINAL ANSWER

I'm running Gentoo Linux and I finally solved this by... wait for it... reinstalling `dev-java/icedtea`! I feel like it's a super-lame answer, but it's the *only* thing that worked. A lot of people have had this problem and I hope this helps somebody. I recall reading a bug report a few years ago in OpenJDK or icedtea project about this, but I haven't been able to track that down again. I presume reinstalling worked because I somehow had the old jars with the bug and the new version has the fix, but I can't be 100% certain.

Specifically, I ran:

```bash
sudo emerge -1v dev-java/icedtea
eselect java-vm set user icedtea-8
ANDROID_HOME=/home/daniel/.android-sdk-update-manager /home/daniel/.android-sdk-update-manager/tools/bin/sdkmanager --list
```

If you are using Ubuntu, Debian, etc. I presume you'll want to `apt install --reinstall openjdk-8-jre` or whatever your Java 8 package is called.